# Serialize output from two Popen subprocesses

Tags: python, subprocess

How I can I use subprocess.Popen to start two processes, print the output from one, and then when it completes, print the output from the second?

I'm writing a build script and it calls several tools that output progress text. I want the user to **see this progress text** so they know it's working, but I want the text from different tools **separated** so it's understandable.

I currently have something like this but it doesn't print anything until process `p` completes:

```py
import subprocess

# replace these with processes that take ~1min
cmd1 = "ls.exe c:/Users".split(" ")
cmd2 = "ls.exe c:/Windows".split(" ")

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.run(cmd2, check=True)

if p.wait() != 0:
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cmd1, p.stderr)

for line in p.stdout:
    print(line, end='')
```

Instead, I want it to print the output of `cmd2` and then print the output of `cmd1`. (There's no guarantee that either finishes first.) If `cmd1` hasn't finished, it should print whatever's available and then send the rest of its output to stdout.

Related: [*How to synchronize the output of Python subprocess*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205990/how-to-synchronize-the-output-of-python-subprocess), but I don't want to wait for processes to complete before printing output.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it's pretty simple: move the print loop before the `wait()`.

If you read a limited amount from `p.stdout`, it won't block for long. So it will read one line, print, read the next, print, etc. If it gets to the point where there's no line to read, it blocks until a line is available and continues the loop.

The for loop calls `p.stdout.readline()` which reads until it hits a newline character. Calling `p.stdout.read()` would block until the process sent EOF, so it wouldn't give the desired behaviour. I don't know if there's a way to dump `p.stdout` to `sys.stdout`.

```py
import subprocess

cmd1 = "ls.exe c:/Windows".split(" ")
cmd2 = "ls.exe c:/Users".split(" ")

print(cmd2, flush=True)
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.run(cmd2, check=True)

# Read from stdout *before* calling wait()
print(cmd1)
for line in p.stdout:
    print(line, end='')

if p.wait() != 0:
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cmd1, p.stderr)
```